# Remove question mark from URL query

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Is there any way I can remove the question mark from URL using Mod_Rewrite like this?:

```
domain.com/controller-name?parameter/parameter/parameter
```

to change question mark after controller-name to slash

```
domain.com/controller-name/parameter/parameter/parameter
```

I want to add this to htaccess in PrestaShop, where I send query like this: parameter/parameter/parameter to controller.

Normal Presta URL is `domain.com/index.php?controller=controller-name` and I set on SEO settings friendly URL to this controller to rewrite to only controller-name so SEO friendly URL is domain.com/controller-name .

To send some parameters to this controller I can use URL like this: domain.com/controller-name?(here parameters)

In my controller I grab parameters after question mark ? and show content according to this parameters. The parameters are separated by a slash. So I want to get rid of question mark and replace it by slash to get: `domain.com/controller-name/(here parameters)`  with parameters I want to look like this `domain.com/controller-name/parameter/parameter/`

When I use URL `domain.com/controller-name/parameter/parameter/` shows error 404 and Presta don't see that I want content from `controller-name`.

I think it is achievable by mod_rewrite rule in .htaccess, but I don't know how to write rule according to this problem.

OR maybe there is a way to add something to controller or SEO configuration in Presta to work with / instead ? in query... that would be great solution...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the history.pushState and history.popState to change the URL in the browser which won't cause a page reload. But the problem is that old browsers don't support this.

Alternatively, you can set the window.location.hash property to a value that contains whatever state information you need, then either use the window.onhashchange event, or for older browsers that don't support onhashchange (IE < 8, Firefox < 3.6), periodically check to see if the hash has changed (using setInterval for example) and update the page. You will also need to check the hash value on page load to set up the initial content.

If you're using jQuery there's a hashchange plugin that will use whichever method the browser supports. I'm sure there are plugins for other libraries as well.

One thing to be careful of is colliding with ids on the page, because the browser will scroll to any element with a matching id.

Comment: Thanks for replay, but I don't think that your proposal is good one. Idea is to remove question mark from link which represent query string. It's necessary to URL be friendly. It's all needed to better SEO. So in your suggestion URL will be with question mark, and after load jQuery will remove him. Unfortunately it's not a solution...